# Bypass Certificate Error

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-7, internet-explorer-8, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to bypass/ignore/disable certificate errors ? I'm encountering this on IE8 and the server is using IIS 7. The situation is I created a asp.net website and Im accessing this website using "https". My other website got no problem with this scenario but my other website does. I just want to do the trick within web.config or any other way except (server side code, creating Self Signed certificate, redirecting the website).

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: It's your browser which is showing the certificate error, so changing the server-side web.config won't help you at all (if it's even possible).

Answer (score 0):

why are you seeing error to begin with? if you don't have certificate installed then make sure your not using HTTPS anywhere on your site.

its browser based...you can not control the warning message.

Comment: I dont have certificate installed but i wonder why is the other site I deployed does not encounter this warning message ? The first site does not encounter the error but the second site which have a linked on the first https site encounter this warning message.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In IE follow the steps below. It works for me.

1. Click Tools and select Internet Options
2. Click the Security
3. Select "Trusted Sites" icon and set the Security level to "Medium Low".
4. Close all the Windows. Then open the browser.

Comment: This will work ONLY for your Computer, you cannot disable it on webserver.